How to configure `MockMvc` to apply a RequestPostProcessor to all requests?
Given:
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(
            authorize - >
            authorize
            .requestMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer.jwt(withDefaults()))
        .oauth2Login(withDefaults());

    return http.build();
}

public class HelloControllerTests {

    @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnWorld() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/hello").with(oauth2Login()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello, World!")));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnBob() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/hello").with(oauth2Login()).param("name", "bob"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello, Bob")));
    }
}

I have a good amount of tests, and would be a lot of repetition to include with(oauth2Login()) in endpoint tests.
How can i make mockMvc always include with(oauth2Login()) in all requests?

just create a method called getWithOauth2(String url) that does get(url).with(oauth2Login())

This does not solve the problem witb repetition, now all hundreds of tests would have getWithOauth2, i am looking for a way to configure MockMVC directly

You could add a MockMvcBuilderCustomizer to your test classpath. This example would automatically inject csrf token. It should work for another postProcessor as well.
@Component
public class MyMockMvcCustomizer implements MockMvcBuilderCustomizer {

  @Override
  public void customize(ConfigurableMockMvcBuilder<?> builder) {
    builder.defaultRequest(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api").with(csrf()));
  }
}


That being said, for authentication I usually inject the context with @WithSecurityContext. There is a bit of configuration to write, but once done, it is more flexible when you want to test with multiple users / roles / access.
